# ASP.NET TicketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieValue) returns null

Tags: .net, authentication, encryption, cookies, asp.net-core

I am trying to decrypt an authentication cookie set by another .NET 4.6.2 MVC app which was created with the following in the Startup.Auth:

```
            TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
                new DataProtectorShim(
                    DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Keys\"))
                        .CreateProtector("blah")))
```

This is what I'm doing to try and decrypt it:

```
//  Create a data protector to facilitate in decrypting the cookie.
var provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(keyDirectory));
var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(dataProtectorPurpose);

//  Decrypt the cookie, obtaining an authentication ticket.
var ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
var ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieValue);
```

This was working fine up until I started to do some Identity customisation. I have created a new IdentityUser which inherits from IdentityUser just so I can add a few extra fields. Is it failing to read the identity now maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this through a lot of playing about.

It turned out to be a combination of the following issues:

- The purpose and sub purposes strings provided to the DataProtectionProvider CreateProtector method were not set to "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
  "Cookies", "v2". I just had them as another string value as from reading the docs, I thought this could be just any string, as long as they were the same between the apps needing to share the cookie.

---

- One of the apps was using version 1.1.2 of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection NuGet package, whereas the other was using version 1.1.1. I upgraded the 1.1.1 -> 1.1.2.

All seems to work fine now. So having a custom user identity in one app which is not in the other does not matter, the cookie can still be understood and a ClaimsIdentity extracted.

Comment: Hello. Can you help me out? I am trying to share Identity cookie from one asp.net API to another (which DOES NOT use Identity). What is the "legal" mechanism of extracting the claims? The sharing is done. All my APIs receive the cookie. But the other API's cannot extract the full information about the claims. Can you explain how this can be achieved?